# Stereo recording on iPhone with bluetooth microphones

Tags: ios, iphone, core-audio, audiounit

I'm developing a hearing aid app, and hope to record in stereo so that I could do some noise reduction or sound localization. I've searched a lot and learnt that iphone 6 has 3 built-in mic, and I COULD NOT record from more than one simultaneously.

My first question is that if that's true, does it mean that Apps like Skype all use just one microphone, without an additional noise reduction microphone?

My second question is that, what if I use an external device, such as a bluetooth headset with two microphones? Could I get the input data from the two microphones simultaneously? Any sample code or direction would be appreciated.